# Genymotion Android emulator for Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, genymotion

I've problem about using Genymotion Android emulator for xamarin development. 
I have intalled Genymotion desktop app and several Android devices within it. Whenever i run any of the installed device in Genymotion desktop app via `start` button, it works fine but there is no Genymotion emulator in the list of available emulators in Visual Studio, neither in Xamarin studio (There are only built-in Android Emulators and devices installed in Xamarin Android player). 
I found some articles about using Genymotion Emulator for Xamarin and all of them says that :

> Both Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio with Xamarin discover it, no problem

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise Edition, Xamarin business editiorn and free edition of Genymotion, if that matters.

Comment: if you list devices via `adb devices` does your Genymotion device (that is current running) show up? If you have not started a Genymotion instance, start one first.

Comment: Thanks @RobertN for reply  
<br/>
Yes, it shows up like this. <br/> <br/>
` List of devices attached
someIp:5555     device `

Comment: Since `adb` see it, it show work. In Xamarin Studio it should be showing up a 'physical device' not a virtual one...

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobertN . As i see problem was that Genymotion android emulator was not started, after i started it from Genymotion desktop app it become visible in Visual studio.

Comment: Glad to help. And yes Genymotion does not establish itself as a std emulator and thus will appear as a physical device so unless it running an Android image (via VirtualBox), XamarinStudio (and other IDEs) will not see it. There are plugins to other IDEs to enable them to start Geny and `then` connect to it over its published ip:port, but Xamarin is not one of those IDEs

Comment: Thanks @RobertN, probably that's why Xamarin Android Player does not need to be started in order to see it in available devices in Visual studio.

Comment: I added this as an answer to help the next people, accept it as an answer if you wish...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Genymotion needs to be *running* for Xamarin Studio (and thus Xamarin's VS plugin) to see it.

Once your Genymotion virtual device is actually running, then Xamarin will see it as a '**physical device**' that it can deploy to.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it does not appear at first.
To fix it you need to close and reopen your solution. Then Genymotion device emulator will start appearing in VS.